# What is best way to pass variables between GUI in Winforms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've WinForms program with 2 GUI's. I work with one `GUI` and open another `GUI` using

```
        var gui = new FormGui("SomeVar", someOthervar);
        gui.ShowDialog();
```

I use `ShowDialog()` or `Show()` depending on what I need to get.  When I'm done I would like to pass results (sometimes it's 2 strings, sometimes it's more then that) back to the `Mother GUI` which called `Child GUI`.

What's the best way to do that? I was thinking about using global variables but not sure if that's best approach?

Comment: Aside from the specific problem - generally avoid global variables wherever you can. Not at all cost, but wherever you can pass something, pass it. Being able to track a value's way and its modifications through your code method call by method call is simply invaluable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create properties on your `FormGui` and set those within the form. When you're done with the form, you can grab those properties from your reference to the form:

```
var gui = new FormGui("SomeVar", someOthervar);
gui.ShowDialog();
var result = gui.Result;
```

**EDIT:** Regarding your comment:

Say your child form has some button on it or something that the user can interact with. Or if there's a close button they click on:

```
private void buttonCloseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Result = new ResultObject()....
}
```

**EDIT #2** Regarding your second comment:

Yes, on your FormGui class, you need to define an object called `Result`:

```
public partial class FormGui : Form
{
   public ResultObject Result {get;set;}
}
```

`ResultObject` is just something I'm making up. The point being that you're in control of `FormGui`, so you can add any property you want, and then access it on the `FormGui` object.

Comment: How do I set the gui.Result from within the `ChildGui` ?

Comment: I must say i can't find this.Result or Results when doing this inside buttonClick in childWindow? DO I have to somehow define the property first ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property on the `FormGui` class that contains the results you want to use in the parent form.

Also, you can use the result of `ShowDialog()` to pass information back as well - although this is limited values of the [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) enum.

Answer (score 0):

You can call with ShowDialog, on the child window, use a new public property to set the result, and when you close the dialog the parent GUI should be able to see the result in the next code line.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by **BFree** is enough for your task

I am suggesting easy way to add properties to all forms

Make a new class extend it with System.Windows.Form

```
public class Form : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
   //add properties
}
```

Check your properties in your forms